# How to index a firestore document map item for listview

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to grab each of the map items from my firestore test project and display them into the listview. My current data structure looks like this

[image: Data Structure]

Here is my ListView Builder

[List View Builder Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nuIF.png)

The error I get is

> NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called null. Receiver: null Tried calling;

How would I get it to build each of the items in the 'place' map?

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Replace the image with the actual code, and use the formatting features of Stack Overflow to make it look right.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

From the image provided, it seems like `snapshot.data` is `null` at the build time. You're using `snapshot.connectionState` as your build indicator, but `snapshot.data` may still be `null` after the connection state is no longer `waiting`.

## Solution

To fix this, change `if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)` to `if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting || !snapshot.hasData)`.

This way, your list only builds if the snapshot actually has data.